# Add value of playing cards - with pointers and structures

Tags: c

I'm going through some c programming questions and I'm currently stuck on a pointer related question

Q: Write a function that takes the values of a two-card blackjack HAND as input, and returns the point total of the hand. The value
 of the cards '2' through '9' is equal to their face value, the cards 'T', 'K', 'Q', 'J' are worth 10 points and the ace ('A') is worth 11 points
 unless it comes with another ace, then that second ace is worth 1 point. The program should be able to catch incorrect input.

Examples:
Enter cards: A Q
 The score is 21

Enter cards: A A
 The score is 12

I've tackled this question before, but this time I'd have to use pointers which I'm still fairly new towards. Getting card values and calculating cards must be done in one function. Here's what i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HAND 2
struct player_hand
{
     char card1;
     char card2;
};


void getHandValue(struct player_hand * hnd_ptr, char size, char size2)
{
    int first_card;
    int second_card;

    //get cards from user
    scanf("%c %c",&hnd_ptr->card1, &hnd_ptr->card2);
    printf("Enter Cards: %c %c", &hnd_ptr->card1, &hnd_ptr->card2);

    //check value of first card in hand 
    if(hnd_ptr->card1<='9' && hnd_ptr->card1>='2')
    {
        first_card=(int)hnd_ptr->card1 -48;

    }
    //check for special cards: king, queen, jack, ten
    else if(hnd_ptr->card1=='T'||hnd_ptr->card1=='K'||hnd_ptr->card1=='Q'||hnd_ptr->card1=='J')
    {
        first_card=10;
    }
    //if first card is Ace
    else if(hnd_ptr->card1=='A')
    {
        first_card=11;
    }
    else
    {
        //card not valid
        printf("Not a valid card: %c",hnd_ptr->card1);
        return;
    }

    //check value of 2nd card
    if(hnd_ptr->card2<='9' && hnd_ptr->card2>='2')
    {
        second_card=(int)hnd_ptr->card2 -48;

    }
    //if 2nd card is a special kind
    else if(hnd_ptr->card2=='T'||hnd_ptr->card2=='K'||hnd_ptr->card2=='Q'||hnd_ptr->card2=='J')
    {
        second_card=10;
    }
    //if 2nd card is Ace
    else if(hnd_ptr->card2=='A')
    {
        if(hnd_ptr->card1=='A')
        second_card=1;
        else
        second_card=11;
    }
    else
    {
        //if 2nd card not valid
        printf("Not a valid card: %c",hnd_ptr->card2);
        return;
    }

    add cards
    printf("\nThe total card value is: %d",first_card+second_card);

}

//call function, test if works
//calling it wrong?
int main(void) 
{
    struct player_hand hnd [HAND]  =  { {'A', 'A'}};
    getHandValue (hnd, HAND);
    return;
}
```

Comment: what problem exactly you are facing now ?

Comment: If you are passing the pointer to a structure, no need to make arguments for hands. You can access them using the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few bugs.

Incorrect call in `main`.

The function doesn't need size arguments and if it did they should be `int`.

Bad `return` from `main`.

In the function, the `printf` is wrong.

Things are much more complicated than they need to be because the `struct` uses two scalars instead of an array.

I've created two versions of your program. One with bugs annotated. And another that cleans things up.

Here's the annotated version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HAND 2

struct player_hand {
    char card1;
    char card2;
};

// NOTE/BUG: use 'int' for size and size2
void
getHandValue(struct player_hand *hnd_ptr, char size, char size2)
{
    int first_card;
    int second_card;

    // get cards from user
    scanf("%c %c", &hnd_ptr->card1, &hnd_ptr->card2);

// NOTE/BUG: this would print the _address_ of the values vs. the values
    printf("Enter Cards: %c %c", &hnd_ptr->card1, &hnd_ptr->card2);

// NOTE/BUG [sort of]: the code below is cut-n-paste replication because you
// have separate card1 and card2 in the struct -- this "cries out" for an
// array and a loop. Consider the general case where you have 5 cards in the
// hand (e.g. five card charlie). The code would be easier even with an array
// of only two

    // check value of first card in hand
    if (hnd_ptr->card1 <= '9' && hnd_ptr->card1 >= '2') {
        first_card = (int) hnd_ptr->card1 - 48;

    }
    // check for special cards: king, queen, jack, ten
    else if (hnd_ptr->card1 == 'T' || hnd_ptr->card1 == 'K' || hnd_ptr->card1 == 'Q' || hnd_ptr->card1 == 'J') {
        first_card = 10;
    }
    // if first card is Ace
    else if (hnd_ptr->card1 == 'A') {
        first_card = 11;
    }
    else {
        // card not valid
        printf("Not a valid card: %c", hnd_ptr->card1);
        return;
    }

    // check value of 2nd card
    if (hnd_ptr->card2 <= '9' && hnd_ptr->card2 >= '2') {
        second_card = (int) hnd_ptr->card2 - 48;

    }
    // if 2nd card is a special kind
    else if (hnd_ptr->card2 == 'T' || hnd_ptr->card2 == 'K' || hnd_ptr->card2 == 'Q' || hnd_ptr->card2 == 'J') {
        second_card = 10;
    }
    // if 2nd card is Ace
    else if (hnd_ptr->card2 == 'A') {
        if (hnd_ptr->card1 == 'A')
            second_card = 1;
        else
            second_card = 11;
    }
    else {
        // if 2nd card not valid
        printf("Not a valid card: %c", hnd_ptr->card2);
        return;
    }

    printf("\nThe total card value is: %d", first_card + second_card);
}

//call function, test if works
//calling it wrong?
int
main(void)
{

// NOTE: based on usage, this is only an array because you're not using &hnd
// below
    struct player_hand hnd[HAND] = {
        {'A', 'A'}
    };

// NOTE/BUG: too few arguments to function, but why pass count at all?
    getHandValue(hnd, HAND);

// NOTE/BUG: need to return value (e.g. return 0)
    return;
}
```

---

Here's the cleaned up version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CARDS_PER_HAND      2

struct player_hand {
    char card[CARDS_PER_HAND];
};

void
getHandValue(struct player_hand *hnd_ptr)
{
    int idx;
    int card;
    int sum;
    int count[CARDS_PER_HAND];

    // get cards from user
    printf("Enter Cards:");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (idx = 0;  idx < CARDS_PER_HAND;  ++idx)
        scanf(" %c", &hnd_ptr->card[idx]);

    // print cards
    printf("Cards entered:");
    for (idx = 0;  idx < CARDS_PER_HAND;  ++idx)
        printf(" %c", hnd_ptr->card[idx]);
    printf("\n");

    for (idx = 0;  idx < CARDS_PER_HAND;  ++idx) {
        card = hnd_ptr->card[idx];

        // simple cards
        if (card <= '9' && card >= '2') {
            count[idx] = (card - '2') + 2;
            continue;
        }

        switch (card) {
        case 'A':
            count[idx] = 11;
            if ((idx == 1) && (count[0] == 11))
                count[idx] = 1;
            break;

        case 'T':
        case 'K':
        case 'Q':
        case 'J':
            count[idx] = 10;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Not a valid card: %c", card);
            return;
            break;
        }
    }

    sum = 0;
    for (idx = 0;  idx < CARDS_PER_HAND;  ++idx)
        sum += count[idx];

    printf("The total card value is: %d\n", sum);
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct player_hand hnd;

    getHandValue(&hnd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Jeez, thanks for that! I'll look over your code and study it. Really wanna get the hang of pointers but its a bit tough.

Comment: You're welcome! The key point I guess is that whenever there seems to be a lot of replication of verbiage (i.e. simplified by the `card = hnd_ptr->card[idx]` which allows use of `card`, which is simpler, in the remainder of the loop) or code duplication [having the same code spelled out separately for each card], it's an indication that the architecture should be refactored. With more experience, you'll be able to spot these simplifications during initial coding, but, if you find yourself "painting yourself into a corner", it's find to stop, take a breath, and rework things.

Answer (score 1):

If, in addition to the other answers, your intent was to pass a 2-hand array, you would need to handle both hands within a loop in your scoring function. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HAND 2

struct player_hand
{
    char card1;
    char card2;
};

void getHandValue (struct player_hand *hnd_ptr, int size)
{
    int first_card;
    int second_card;

    /* get cards from user */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf ("\nenter cards for hand %d (card1 card2): ", i);

        /* you must handle the '\n' that remains after last char */
        if (scanf ("%c %c%*c", &hnd_ptr[i].card1,  &hnd_ptr[i].card2) != 2) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid entry.\n");
            return;
        }
        printf ("you entered: %c %c\n", hnd_ptr[i].card1, hnd_ptr[i].card2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        /* check value of first card in hand */
        if(hnd_ptr[i].card1 <= '9' && hnd_ptr[i].card1 >= '2')
        {
            first_card = (int)hnd_ptr[i].card1 - '0';

        }
        /* check for special cards: king, queen, jack, ten */
        else if (hnd_ptr[i].card1 == 'T' || hnd_ptr[i].card1 == 'K' || 
                hnd_ptr[i].card1 == 'Q' || hnd_ptr[i].card1 == 'J')
        {
            first_card = 10;
        }
        /* if first card is Ace */
        else if (hnd_ptr[i].card1 == 'A')
        {
            first_card = 11;
        }
        else
        {
            /* card not valid */
            printf("Not a valid card: %c",hnd_ptr[i].card1);
            return;
        }

        /* check value of 2nd card */
        if(hnd_ptr[i].card2 <= '9' && hnd_ptr[i].card2 >= '2')
        {
            second_card=(int)hnd_ptr[i].card2 - '0';

        }
        /* if 2nd card is a special kind */
        else if (hnd_ptr[i].card2 == 'T' || hnd_ptr[i].card2 == 'K' || 
                hnd_ptr[i].card2 == 'Q' || hnd_ptr[i].card2 == 'J')
        {
            second_card = 10;
        }
        /* if 2nd card is Ace */
        else if (hnd_ptr[i].card2 == 'A')
        {
            if (hnd_ptr[i].card1 == 'A')
                second_card = 1;
            else
                second_card = 11;
        }
        else
        {
            /* if 2nd card not valid */
            printf ("Not a valid card: %c", hnd_ptr[i].card2);
            return;
        }

        /* add cards */
        printf ("\nThe total cards value (hand %d) is: %d\n", 
                i, first_card + second_card);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct player_hand hnd[HAND]  =  { {'A', 'A'}, {'A', 'A'} };
    getHandValue (hnd, HAND);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cards

enter cards for hand 0 (card1 card2): A A
you entered: A A

enter cards for hand 1 (card1 card2): 8 K
you entered: 8 K

The total cards value (hand 0) is: 12

The total cards value (hand 1) is: 18
```

If your intent was not to pass an array of struct, then obviously looping would not be necessary. Note: two loops were used. The first to get the cards for both hands, the second to compute the scores for both. (you could do it with one, but it looked as if you intended to have all cards entered before scoring) Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the address of `hnd` to the function `getHandValue()`. To do this you have to pass the address using the **&** operator `getHandValue(&hnd)`.

You're also not initializing `struct player_hand hnd` correctly. There's one set of `{}` too many.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edited version of your `main()` code that works, just some minor edits to how your pointer is set up.

```
// main
int main(void) 
{
    // minor edits to fix the code here
    struct player_hand hnd = {'A', 'A'};
    struct player_hand *hndPtr = &hnd;

    getHandValue (hndPtr);
    return 0;
}
```